# Unwanted visitors detected

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

My firsts signify education
My seconds axial examination
My thirds medical location
My fourths denote radiation
My fifths state abbreviation
My whole is blood contamination
My parts each two in variation
My consonants lack reiteration

When I am shaped like my first
Rows from my parts that may burst
Adding flipped to in empty spaces
My second column through blood races
Sinking first precedes one year
After it sympathize with fear
New second across for relaxation
And fourth row now for documentation
Finally trademarked my column third
Except my seconds, none a full word

Who am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to this puzzle is:

> **BACTEREMIA**

*My firsts signify education*
*My seconds axial examination*
*My thirds medical location*
*My fourths denote radiation*
*My fifths state abbreviation*

> Splitting this 10-letter word into 5 pairs of letters, and thinking of these pairs as 'firsts', 'seconds', 'thirds, 'fourths' and 'fifths', we have:
>
>  Firsts = **BA** - Bachelor of Arts degree (*signifying education*);
>  Seconds = **CT** - Computed Tomography, a 3D axial scanning technique (*axial examination*);
>  Thirds = **ER** - Emergency Room (*medical location*);
>  Fourths = **EM** - Electro-Magnetic (*radiation*);
>  Fifths = **IA** - the *state abbreviation* for Iowa.

*My whole is blood contamination*
*My parts each two in variation*
*My consonants lack reiteration*

> Bacteremia is the contamination of blood with bacteria (also described by the title, which sounds like an immune response to infection). *My parts each two in variation* merely confirms that the clues to the first part above relate to two-letter sequences. Note also that the five consonants of the word do not repeat (*lack reiteration*).

*When I am shaped like my first*
*Rows from my parts that may burst*

> Now comes an ASCII part, similar to [another recent riddle of the OP's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91162/best-company-ever/91165#91165)! Shape the letters of the word 'BACTEREMIA' like 'its first', i.e. a letter B:
>
> ```
>  BA
>  C T
>  ER
>  E M
>  IA
> ```

*Adding flipped to in empty spaces*
*My second column through blood races*

> Adding the letters of 'to', but *flipped* (i.e. in reverse order) gives:
>
> ```
>  BA
>  COT
>  ER
>  ETM
>  IA
> ```
>
> By reading down the second column you can read the word **AORTA** - the major blood vessel *through which blood races*.

*Sinking first precedes one year*
*After it sympathize with fear*
*New second across for relaxation*
*And fourth row now for documentation*
*Finally trademarked my column third*

> These lines refer to other 'words' we can read in the diagram:
>
>  *Sinking first* = first column downwards: B CEE I, which can be interpreted as **BC ONE** - the year which preceded AD 1 in the calendar (*precedes one year*).
>
>  *Second across* = second row left to right: **COT** - a bed (*for relaxation*).
>
>  *Fourth row now* = fourth row left to right: **ETM** - Electronic Technical Manual (*documentation*).
>
>  *My column third* = third column downwards: **TM** - the abbreviation for *trademarked*.

*Except my seconds, none a full word*

> Note that the only ones of these which are real words rather than abbreviations or acronyms are those in the second row and second column, as described here.

And thus it is solved!

Comment: Wow, nice job. I'd solved the firsts and thirds, but was stuck on **Bq** for the fourths.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Thanks :) It helps that I work in cancer research, where we use a lot of imaging types, including both of the ones mentioned here!