# A normal Vowelburger™ riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, letters

*<sup>Inspired by Avi's [Vowelburger™ Riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92931/vowelburger-riddle)</sup>*
I ordered 5 plain Vowelburgers™ with lettuce in addition to the patty and buns. Help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

| Patty | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| A | sports |
| E | normal |
| I | law |
| O | cotton |
| U | Spain |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The menu includes buns **B** and **L** with **L**ettuce, and the burgers are
>
>  - BALL (sports)
>  - BELL (shape of normal distribution curve)
>  - BILL (law)
>  - BOLL (cotton)
>  - BULL (national animal of Spain)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I realise you wanted the answer to look smarter (hey, I'm always in favour of a tidy answer), but maybe in future give gentle nudges to your answerers to guide them towards ways they could improve their answer rather than overriding it yourself - in the process of doing this you've changed JMP's reasoning for one of their responses, presumably to reflect your original intentions; it might have been nice to discuss that difference in opinion in the comments first - just some 'food'(!) for thought. (If this *was* discussed in comments which have since been deleted, I apologise!)

Comment: No problem, @Stiv, you guessed it right!

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Okay. Rubio once made a similar point on one of [my answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/91165/60644) that had been 'ghost-solved' by the OP in this way - just passing on the advice :)

Comment: @stiv; it's ok, I don't mind Ebe's edit, mine was close enough: "The best example of this is the bull which is the national animal of Spain. In Spain, bull-fighting is a cultural activity that is widely followed across the country. This popularity has led to the bull being a national animal." (from https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/national-animals-of-european-countries.html), and bullfighting isn't unique to Spain. Ebe probably wanted the answer to match to his question more accurately, but I agree he should have asked first!

Comment: Pardon me, @JMP, I’ll keep that in mind next time :)